# Cannot start internal HTTP server... IntelliJ stopped working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, proxy, firewall, pac

I have `IntelliJ` and other development tools stopped working today.

`IntelliJ` says on start:

> Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript
>   debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your
>   firewall settings and restart IntelliJ IDEA

Before this happened I was receiving strange errors on loopback connection on build which is now gone. Currently it says

> Error:failed to create a child event loop

`Gradle` build says:

> Protocol family unavaliable

Disabling firewall does not help.

**UPDATE**

IntelliJ log is full of messages like this:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:165)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$5.create(MavenServerManager.java:494)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$5.create(MavenServerManager.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getRemoteId(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:169)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.access$100(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$1.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:105)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport$3.compute(RemoteProcessSupport.java:256)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:181)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.a(RemoteProcessSupport.java:252)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:162)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 57 more
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found the root of the problem: this was caused by [proxy autoconfiguration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config). By some reason address of `127.0.0.1` was processing by proxy and was leading to the web page of proxy server. The addition of

```
function FindProxyForURL(url,host)
{
   if( host == '127.0.0.1' ) {
      return "DIRECT";
   }
```

to `wpad.dat` helped but I still don't understand an entire effect. I have proxy for a long time and it was no causing such an effect previously.

So I think this is also somehow related with `IPv6` or something.